# Where can I register .tw domain extensions?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I'm currently looking to register the Taiwanese version of my company's domain. Dynadot, doesn't register domains with that extension. I found a few places on the web: Godaddy has them, and a fewer smaller, shadier places claim to have them, but they start at $39.99/year which seems a bit outrageous. Has anyone found a more affordable, reliable registration company for .tw domains?

Comment: `$39.99/year which seems a bit outrageous` - try registering a `.com.au`!

Answer (score 1):

The `.tw` domain is quite expensive. You won't probably be able to buy a `.tw` domain for less that 40$/year.

The only provider I found cheaper than GoDaddy and equally famous is [name.com](http://www.name.com/).
You can buy a `.tw` domain for 34$.

Comment: 101domain has it for $33/year ($30/year if you register for 10 years). Seems like the official registrars have jacked up the prices to about $30/year. You could try your hand at [registering from them directly](http://www.twnic.net/english/dn/dn_01.htm), but aside from most being in Chinese only their websites seem exceptionally incompetently designed.