# Does anyone know where I can register a website with a .cat TLD?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains

I have been looking to register a website with the TLD '.cat'. I know it was created for catalan websites, but I want to do a domain hack, like bit.ly (which appears to be English).

But all the hosts I've looked at just allow you to register a site with generic TLDs, such as .com, .org, .info etcetera. I've been searching for a company which can host a .cat website for a while now and just can't find one, I also tried a whois (which I don't really understand) on .cat sites but that's not my area, so I was unsuccessful in locating the hosting company of other .cat sites.

I've looked at similar questions, such as [Where can I register .tw domain extensions?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6485/where-can-i-register-tw-domain-extensions) but no joy. I would really appreciate a link or pointer in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Libya's usage restrictions aren't the same as the PuntCAT Foundation's. If you put up a website without [Catalan content](http://www.domini.cat/faq/index.php#p2.1.) you risk losing the domain.

Comment: Thx Peter, I read this on wikipedia, but it's good to get a reminder. I will just create a button to switch the language to catalan ;) (hopefully that shall apease the powers that be)

Comment: @Peter: For English-speakers, a link to the [English version of the FAQ](http://www.domini.cat/en_faq/index.php#t20) might be more useful. :-)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, home, if he can't read the Catalan FAQ they'll probably reject his application anyway :P

Comment: *I've been searching for a company which can host a .cat*  registering a domain name and hosting a website are two different things. IT is true that some companies could do both for you, but you can also use two separate ones... and any decent webhosting company should be able to host a website on any domain name whatever the TLD. As for registering, the steps are always the same: find the registry, go on its website, where normally you will have a list of accredited registrars. For gTLDs, they need ICANN accreditations which you can find on ICANN website. But there are resellers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [this page](http://www.domini.cat/com_registrar.html). You will need to translate it into English to continue. It contains the instructions for how to register a .cat domain.

Comment: Fantastic answer. This is just what I needed. Many thanks dude!

Comment: You don't need to translate it, there's an [English version of the page](http://www.domini.cat/en_com_registrar.html) too.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen cheers!

Comment: The English version is now [here](http://fundacio.cat/en/domini).

Answer (score 1):

> The .cat domain is not territorial, but applies to all the
>   Catalan-speaking community. Therefore, if you fulfill the conditions
>   described above (domain naming conventions and web related to the
>   Catalan culture or language), you may register a .cat domain
>   regardless of where you live.